# How to adjust Jquery jtable column width in php?

Tags: php, jquery, jtable

```
paid_date: {
    title: 'Paid Date',
    sorting: 'id DESC',
    type: 'date',
    width: '20%',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setMinWidth(200) and setPreferredWidth(200) to set column width.

Answer (score 0):

jTable is designed to fit it's container element, not for a fixed width. So, all columns will be completed to 100%. If you want to fix table's width, set it's container's width.

But

Width of the column for this field in the table. Can be a percantage value (ex: '30%'). It's required if the field is shown on the table. It's best to complete all shown field widths to 100%.